# Using urllib2 to do a SOAP POST, but I keep getting an error

Tags: python, api, soap, post, typeerror

I am trying to do an API call via a SOAP POST and I keep getting
"TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object." @ data = urllib.urlencode(values)

```
SM_TEMPLATE = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <AutotaskIntegrations xmlns="http://Autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/">
      <PartnerID>partner id</PartnerID>
    </AutotaskIntegrations>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <getThresholdAndUsageInfo xmlns="http://Autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/">
    </getThresholdAndUsageInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

values = SM_TEMPLATE%()
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(site, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `urllib.urlencode` function expects a sequence of key-value pairs or a mapping type like `dict`:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode([('a','1'), ('b','2'), ('b', '3')])
'a=1&b=2&b=3'
```

To perform an SOAP HTTP POST, you should leave the SM_TEMPLATE blob as-is and set it as the POST body, then add a Content-Type header for the POST body's encoding and charset. For example:

```
data = SM_TEMPLATE
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
    }
req = urllib2.Request(site, data, headers)
```

Comment: I also need to add 'soapAction': 'GetAllItem' for my request to get it work

Answer (score 0):

See the code below as an example, it may help you to solve your SOAP request using urllib2 for Python 2.6.6. It worked for me calling an Oracle Data Integrator (Oracle ODI).Obviously, You MUST adapt the values for thes ones that fit in your case:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://alexmoleiro.com:20910/oraclediagent/OdiInvoke?wsdl"

post_data = """<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        what_you_want_to_send_in_a_correct_format
    </Body>
</Envelope>
"""

http_headers = {
    "Accept": "application/soap+xml,multipart/related,text/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

}

request_object = urllib2.Request(url, post_data, http_headers)

#DELETE THIS BLOCK IF YOU ARE NOT USING PROXIES
http_proxy_server = "10.1.2.3"
http_proxy_port = "8080"
http_proxy_realm = http_proxy_server
http_proxy_full_auth_string = "http://%s:%s" % (http_proxy_server, http_proxy_port)
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': http_proxy_full_auth_string})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
#END OF --> DELETE THIS BLOCK IF YOU ARE NOT USING PROXIES

response = urllib2.urlopen(request_object)
html_string = response.read()
print html_string
```

Any feedback would be appreciated :-)